# D3.js csv data from id, correct way?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to import data in my bar chart from element with id "**csvdata**", rather then load it on traditional way from external **.csv** file, this time just for testing...

I've made an "**pre**" element, an gave him id as mentioned above,
changed part of script where I load external csv data which looked like this

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data).....
```

into this

```
d3.csv("#csvdata", function(error, data).....
```

and the d3 sucsessfuly loaded d3 document but does not display data in correct way... Seems to me that I need some sort conversion or parse of data, I'm not quite sure so I need your help with this...

you can see my current situation here:http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/r26b9/

here is html code:

```
<pre id="csvdata" style="display:none">
Year,Outcome,Income,+5%
2013,52083,85640,42153
2014,60000,90000,50000
2015,7000,100000,260000
2016,8000,110000,270000
2017,9000,120000,280000
2018,10000,130000,290000
2019,11000,140000,300000
2020,12000,150000,310000
2021,13000,160000,320000
2022,310504,552339,259034
2023,310504,552339,259034
</pre>
```

script:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, 500], .3);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("#csvdata", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Year"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return a.total - b.total; });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Year; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Total");

  var year = svg.selectAll(".year")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Year) + ",0)"; });

  year.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", 0)
    .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});
```

and css styling:

```
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

you can freely edit my jsfiddle linked above, any help or advice is welcome

Answer (score 0):

When you use `d3.csv` like that, it parses the HTML document -- you can't give CSV data like that. You need to provide the data in a way that it can be parsed directly in Javascript. The easiest way to do this is to directly provide the Javascript variables. `d3.csv` is really only meant for loading external CSv files and while you can use the underlying functions to parse CSV directly, it would be a modification that is not quite trivial.